# Is it valid to have two implicit casts in constructing an object in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion

Given the following two constructor signatures, should it be possible to construct a `Couple` with `Couple("George", "Nora")`? My compiler complains with the error shown below. If I call it with `Couple(std::string("George"), std::string("Nora"))` it compiles OK. I'm guessing there's an issue with the implicit casting which surprises me as I though char* to string would be fine.

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(const std::string& name);
};

class Couple
{
    public:
        Coordinate(const Person& p1, const Person& p2, const Optional<Person>& = Optional<Person>());
};

TestCouple.cpp:69: error: no matching function for call to `Couple::Couple(const char[7], const char[5])'
TestCouple.h:24: note: candidates are: Couple::Couple(const Person&, const Person&, const Optional<fox::Person>&)
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, it should work. You should post the full minimal test.

Comment: Is `Coordinate` a typo? Should it not be `Couple` instead?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "implicit cast" in C++. Casts are explicit requests for conversion, using a special cast syntax. What you are after is implicit conversions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, a conversion sequence can't contain more than one implicit user-defined conversion; the standard specifies this in C++11 12.3/4:

> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

In your case, two would be required (`char const[]` to `std::string` to `Person`), and so implicit conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that there is a problem with implicit conversion. It will only do one implicit conversion for a value, so you can do either `Couple(std::string("a"), std::string("b"))` or `Couple(Person("a"), Person("b"))`, for example, but `Couple("a", "b")` would require the compiler to put in two implicit conversions per value. This is not allowed by the standard, because it would cause code that might be hard to understand correctly and be computationally expensive to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Chained implicit conversion is not allowed. If `A` can implicitly convert into `B` and `B` can implicitly convert into `C`, then it doesn't mean that `A` can implicitly convert into `C.`

```
//given three objects as
A a;
B b'
C c;

//premises 
b = a; //a can convert into b (implicitly)
c = b; //b can convert into c (implicitly)

//then it does not follow this
c = a; //a CANNOT convert into c (implicitly)

//you need to write this at least
c = static_cast<B>(a); //ok
```

Comment: "_then it doesn't mean that A can implicitly convert into C._" that is correct. Nitpick: stating that "`b = a` is valid" is not equivalent with stating "A can convert into B".

Comment: @curiousguy: Explain what you're saying. Why `b=a` is valid in the first place here?

Comment: Assuming B is a class type, `b=a` is valid _iff_ overload resolution can find one best match for `b.operator=(a)`. You could as well write `foo(a,b)`, for suitable overloads of `foo`.

Comment: @curiousguy: You should read my answer properly. I said : *If `A` can implicitly convert into `B` ...*

Comment: "_You should read my answer properly._" I did. "_If A can implicitly convert into B ..._" so?

Comment: @curiousguy: then what is the point of your comment when an assumption is already there in my answer that `A` can implicitly convert into `B`? The overload `b.operator=(a)` is not needed!

Comment: @curiousguy: Also, you seem to think that `b=a` is valid **if and only if** *overload resolution can find one best match for b.operator=(a)*. Wrong. There is another thing called *implicit conversion function* which is what I assumed in my answer, *because* which is what this topic is about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14236/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nawaz)